# how to get weekends in current month by using oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I tried this way but i didn't it..

```
SELECT count(*) as weekends  
FROM (
        SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm')+level-1current_dt 
        FROM DualCONNECT 
        BY LEVEL <= last_day(SYSDATE)–TRUNC(SYSDATE,’mm’)+1
     )
WHERE TO_CHAR(current_dt,'dy') IN ('sat','sun');
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: a weekend is given by two days; what if only one is in the current month? for example, what do you expoect for july 2018?

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to count the number of saturdays, sundays and full weekends in the current month.

I use the `'fmday'` and English language for clarity; another way could be the `'D'` format, by relying on the NLS territory, but this is easier to read:

```
select sum(case when dayOfMonth = 'saturday' then 1 else 0 end) as numberOfSaturdays,
       sum(case when dayOfMonth = 'sunday' then 1 else 0 end) as numberOfSundays,
       sum(case when dayOfMonth = 'sunday' and dayNumber != 1 then 1 else 0 end) as numberOfFullWeekends
from (
        select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'month') + level -1, 'fmday', 'nls_language = English')    as dayOfMonth,
               level as dayNumber
        from dual
        connect by trunc(sysdate, 'month') + level -1 < last_day(sysdate)
     )
```

I consider a full weekend if both saturday and sunday are within the month; to do this, I check whether there is a sunday that is not on the first day of the month, to be sure that even the preceeding saturday is in the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query.

Select count(last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) + level) as
Weekend_number
from dual
where
to_char((last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)) + level), 'DAY') IN ('SATURDAY ', 'SUNDAY ')
connect by level < = to_char(last_day(current_date), 'DD');